# In Ruby on Rails, does changing to_param() have any side effect and what ways can be used to change it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, resources

In some book, it is recommended that to_param is changed to

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\W/, '-').downcase}"
  end

end
```

so that the URL is

```
http://www.mysite.com/stories/1-css-technique-blog
```

instead of

```
http://www.mysite.com/stories/1
```

so that the URL is more search engine friendly.

So probably to_param() doesn't need to be used by other parts of Rails that changing it may have any side effect?  Or maybe the only purpose is to construct a URL for linking?

Another thing is, won't it require to limit the URL size to be less than 2k in length -- will it choke IE if it is more than 2k or maybe the part more than 2k is just ignored by IE and so the URL still works.  It might be better to be limited to 30 or 40 characters or something that will make the URL not exceedingly long.

Also, the `ri` doc of to_param:

```
       class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         def to_param  # overridden
           name
         end
       end
```

if to_param is changed like that, then the link actually won't work, as

```
http://www.mysite.com/stories/1-css-technique-blog
```

will work, but

```
http://www.mysite.com/stories/css-technique-blog
```

will not work as the ID is missing.  Are there other ways to change the to_param method?

**Update:** on second thought, maybe

```
http://www.mysite.com/stories/css-technique-blog
```

won't work well if there are many webpages with similar title.  but then

```
http://www.mysite.com/user/johnchan
```

will work.  Will it be params[:id] being "johnchan"?  So then we will use

```
user = User.find_by_login_name(params[:id])
```

to get the user.  So it just depends on how we use the param on the URL.

```
C:\ror>ri ActiveRecord::Base#to_param
-------------------------------------------- ActiveRecord::Base#to_param
     to_param()
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Returns a String, which Action Pack uses for constructing an URL to
     this object. The default implementation returns this record's id as
     a String, or nil if this record's unsaved.

     For example, suppose that you have a User model, and that you have
     a +map.resources :users+ route. Normally, +user_path+ will
     construct a path with the user object's 'id' in it:

       user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
       user_path(user)  # => "/users/1"

     You can override +to_param+ in your model to make +user_path+
     construct a path using the user's name instead of the user's id:

       class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         def to_param  # overridden
           name
         end
       end

       user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
       user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
```

Comment: You've asked 230 questions and have only accepted answers for 30% of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your url more search engine friendly, you can use the [friendly_id gem](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which makes exactly what you want. Is the easier way I've found to generate search engine friendly permalinks.

Comment: To be explicit, the friendly_id gem generates a slug that supplants the default `id` property for a record. This gem also overrides the model's `to_param` method for URL generation in the views.